# Predefined filters in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

I use Kibana extensively to create all kinds of Dashboards. But a log of the dashboards I have created are essentially filters on a base dashboards. By that I mean that I have created a dashboard that shows the overall health of my application, and whenever I wanted a new dashboard that shows one thing I would apply my filters and save the dashboard as a new dashboard.

My 'derived' dashboards are copies of my base dashboard with varying filters applied. This worked well in the beginning, but as I evolve my 'base' dashboard I run into maintenance hell because I need to recreate all the derived dashboards.

So I wondered if there is a way to embed either a drop down or a row of links at the top, and have these links be predefined filters that are then applied to my dashboard. But I haven't been able to find that anywhere.

The important thing to me is to be able to give the filters an Alias so it is easy to identify what that filter represents. I create a lot of these dashboards so at any given time I will have a couple of dozen derived dashboards.

Is something like that possible or something similar that solves my problem in a better way that I just can't imagine right now.

Comment: What you describe does exist on dashboards at least as of 6.7. What version of Kibana are you referring to?

Comment: We are running 7.8.1. What is this feature called?

Comment: There are two. The first was in 6.3 which has dropdowns and filtering as widgets in dashboards themselves: https://www.elastic.co/blog/interactive-inputs-on-kibana-dashboards. The other is the normal field filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-filter.html. The field filters will stick to the dashboards if you edit, add filters, then save the dashboard after adding the wanted filters.

Comment: Thanks Andy. But those are not exactly what I am looking for. The dropdown will give me a choice between the values of a given property. What I want is a dropdown that allows me to filter on many things at once. So have that one dropdown item be an alias for a set of filters. Does that make sense?